# Why is ordering in class Meta not working?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I made a Twitter -like social network where users see latest posts first using Django 3.1.7.

My model :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=False, default=None)
    user_like = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='likes')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} posted \"{self.content}\" on {self.date_published}'

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date_published',)
```

I query database from `views.py` :

```
@login_required
def following(request):
    authors_followed = Follow.objects.filter(
        follower=request.user).values('author')

    posts = Post.objects.filter(user__in=authors_followed).annotate(
        likes=Count('user_like'))

    return render(request, "network/following.html", {
        'posts': posts
    })
```

But posts are not ordered as expect. When specifying `.order_by('-date_published')` it works. Why is `ordering` in `class Meta` not working? I have done all migrations and migrated the database. `ordering = ['-date_published']` did not work neither.

Comment: We never had an issue with this using Postgres. Your code looks fine.

Comment: Is it sorted correctly if you leave out the `annotate` clause? (just to check)

Comment: Hey, @Risadinha you are right, it works as expected if I remove the `annotate` clause. How can I make it work both the ordering and the annotation?

Comment: In that case, I would recommend trying Postgres first before anything else. You won't be going live with sqlite anyway, and instead of trouble shooting with a pure dev setup, I would suggest switching to your final DB vendor, first. (If undecided yet, use Postgres.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this exact use case was removed in Django 3.1 - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.2/#features-deprecated-in-2-2

In this case, use `.order_by('-date_published'`) on your QuerySet (just as you've done).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had two models: `NameMixing` and `Species`, which inherited from the former. `NameMixing` provided a name field which I wanted to order. `NameMixing` was abstract. Adding `ordering = ['name']` did not work, adding it to `Species` did.

I had a `Meta` class in `Species` as well as in `NameMixing`. In order for `Species` to apply all `Meta` from `NameMixing` (except the abstract) you have to apply inheritance in the `Meta` class too, as [explained in documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes):

> When an abstract base class is created, Django makes any Meta inner
> class  you declared in the base class available as an attribute. If a
> child class  does not declare its own Meta class, it will inherit the
> parent’s Meta. If  the child wants to extend the parent’s Meta class,
> it can subclass it.
>
> Django does make one adjustment to the Meta class of an abstract base
> class: before installing the Meta attribute, it sets abstract=False.
> This  means that children of abstract base classes don’t automatically
> become  abstract classes themselves. To make an abstract base class
> that inherits  from another abstract base class, you need to
> explicitly set abstract=True  on the child.

Answer (score -1):

Each string is a field name with an optional “-” prefix, which indicates descending order. Fields without a leading “-” will be ordered ascending. Use the string “?” to order randomly.

For example, to order by a pub_date field ascending, use this:

```
ordering = ['pub_date']
```

To order by pub_date descending, use this:

```
ordering = ['-pub_date']
```

To order by pub_date descending, then by author ascending, use this:

```
ordering = ['-pub_date', 'author']
```

find more details here

Comment: I have tried using that same syntax for `ordering`, making the migrations, migrating and running the server and it does not work for me. I am not sure what is going on as that is the syntax stated in the docs.